# resolves in angular-ui modal get mixed up

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a very weird problem and as I can't really copy the actual production code here or at least not much of it, you probably can't help me, but I'll try nevertheless.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm doing:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7IjX4jV9sb2Fb6NpmzUZ?p=preview

```
angular.module("hello", [
  "ui.bootstrap",
  "ui.bootstrap.tpls",
  ]);

angular.module("hello").controller("helloCtrl", function($scope, $modal){
  $scope.openModal = function(){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal.tpl.html',
            controller: 'modalCtrl',
            resolve: {
                obj1: function(){
                  return {name:"obj1"};

                },
                obj2: function(){
                  return {name:"obj2"};
                }
            }
        });
  };
});

angular.module("hello").controller("modalCtrl", function($scope, obj1, obj2){
  $scope.obj1 = obj1;
  $scope.obj2 = obj2;
})
```

So I'm opening a modal and resolving the object's to be used in the modal's controller. That example works, but **in the real code the obj1 will be resolved to what was supposed to be obj2, and obj2 will be undefined.** They are also already wrong when they come to controller, not just after attaching them to scope.

In the real project I'm also using ui-router, but the modal is not it's own state and nothing with those names is resolved in this state or parent states.

If someone has any ideas or wild guesses of what could be causing such behavior, I would really appreciate to hear them.

**Edit:**

Here are the most relevant parts of the production code:

modal opening controller:

```
angular.module('cmt').controller('createClusterModalCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, clusterSvc) {
    $scope.openCreateClusterModal = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '..path to template..',
            controller: 'clusterCreateCtrl',
            windowClass: 'cmt-xl-modal-window',
            resolve: {
                initTab: 0,
                validationSettings: function(){
                    //return something simple for debug
                    return {name:"validation"};
                },
                cluster: function(){
                    //return something simple for debug
                    return {name: "cluster"};
                } 
            }
        });
    };
});
```

modal controller:

```
angular.module('cmt').controller('clusterCreateCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, clusterSvc, toastr, initTab, validationSettings, cluster) {
    console.log("validation:");
    console.log(validationSettings);   //will print name: "cluster"
    console.log("cluster:");
    console.log(cluster);              //will print undefined

    ......
```

Comment: Where do you get your obj1 and obj2 from in your production code? Can you add that piece of code somehow? i.e. is it via a http-request or ..?

Comment: It's via a service, but while debugging I changed it to be like the example. Just returning a simple static object. Wait a sec and I'll edit my question to contain some actual code too. I guess it's going to be open source so shouldn't be that critical.

Answer (score 1):

Found the error:

that resolve "initTab: 0" caused it to get the next defined function and so fort. I had to change it to a function that returns 0.

Would someone care to explain why you can not resolve to something else than a function?

Comment: Same thing with me, it would only pass the resolve if it was a function.